# WPF - can't display page content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

I'm trying to display a wpf page inside a wpf window (to reproduce some bug in an isolated environment) and I'm unable to see the page inside the window.

My code is quite simple:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
 <ContentPresenter
        Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=MyPage}"
        ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=MyPage.TT}"
        />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyPage = new Page1();
    }
```

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TT">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="doodle dood doodle da"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any Idea why MainWindow appears empty?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path=MyPage.TT` looks for a property called `TT`, `TT` in all likelihood is *not* a property.

Comment: Yes, I've just added it when it didn't work without it (it still doesn't work so I guess I can get rid of it).. Do I have to use the contentTemplate of the contentpresenter? If so, what is the correct usage?

Comment: @user429400: What are you trying to do? Shouldn't `Page1` be a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx)?

Comment: I'm just trying to recreate a bug I have (in which I have a page which is displayed inside a window).. I need to see that textblock inside the MainWindow

Comment: @user429400: Creating some random class will probably not help. Either `Page1` needs to derive from some visual class so it can be added as content, or if it is data you need a `ContentTemplate` to convert that data. Where you define that template does not matter, you can define it right on the `ContentControl` if you want to, you jsut need to be able to reference it if you add it elsewhere.